# Java String.valueOf(jsonArray) turns UTF-8 encoded content from jsonArray into question marks

Tags: java, json, string, utf-8

I have this json array (of type JSONArray) containing utf-8 encoded strings:

```
    [{
      "success":true,
      "data":[
         {"moduleTitle":"تست",
          "title":"تست دو"}
       ],
       "status":200
    }]
```

And then I would like to get the string value of it.

```
String s = String.valueOf(jsonArray);
```

but the utf-8 strings will be turned into question marks like this:

> "[{
> "success":true,
> "data":[
> {"moduleTitle":"???",
> "title":"??? ??"}
> ],
> "status":200
> }]"

how can I make it show the strings correctly?

Comment: Does this occur when printing it to the (e.g. eclipse) console? It is possible that the console or font doesn't support unicode letters and converts those into `?`.

Comment: You can check to make sure it's not just the console by writing the output to a file.

Comment: I just edited my question. I'm checking my results with postman and with Intellij's debug tool. And it happens only after I convert my json array to string. I would love to know what else the reason could be. @dan1st

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the data using the JVM's default charset, UTF-8 charset most probably is not on your server or local.

Try using this:

```java
String s = String.valueOf(jsonArray);
String string2 = new String(s.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
return new ResponseEntity<String>(string2, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: "you are converting the data using the JVM's default charset" - where do you see that in the code provided? What is the `result` that you're suggesting using? Note that UTF-8 is guaranteed to be present in every JVM.

Comment: I don't see where in my code I could add that line. I just edited my question. Could you take a look and then maybe be a little more specific with your answer? Thanks a lot

Comment: Got the exact same result :( Got any other ideas? @DoctorWho

Comment: from where you are getting this response, any 3rd party services?
and where you intend to send this response?

Comment: Actually the part that I mentioned that it's an API doesn't really matter because `String s` value is what's troubling me. I check it in my IDE debugger. The JSONArray is sown correctly but the string is not. But in case it helps in any way it's not a third party service and I would like to send it to a third party application for use but I'm checking it myself in IDE (Intelij) debugger and postman. @DoctorWho